# Javascript: использование ссылок на переменную (или указателей)

Tags: javascript, указатели, переменные, ссылки

Приветствую

Посмотрел по текущему вопросу несколько источников, но что-то не понял с ответом.

хочу сделать так, чтобы в функцию можно было передавать переменную по ссылке (как в C/C++), а внутри переменной работать уже с этой ссылкой, например:

```
function MyFunc(params)
{
    params.my_data++;
}

let data = 10;

myFunc({
    my_data: &data,
});

console.log(data); // 11
```

Подскажите, позволяет ли такие операции JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

То что именно вы хотите в `js` нереализуемо. Примитивные типы передают по значению, а не по ссылке

```
let a = 0
function foo(a) {
   // здесь своя локальная a
   a = 10
}
console.log(a) // 0
foo(a)
console.log(a) // 0
```

По ссылке передают объекты, поэтому как в ответах ниже можете передавать в качестве аргумента объект

```
let data = { a : 0 }
function foo(data) {
    // хоть здесь опять же локальная переменная data
    // но передается уже по ссылке
    data.a = 10
}
console.log(data.a) // 0
foo(data)
console.log(data.a) // 10
```

Ну и никто не мешает вам просто возвращать значения из функции

```
function foo(a) {
  return a + 10
}

let a = 0
console.log(a)
a = foo(a)
console.log(a)
```

Comment: хорошо бы ещё примеры кода сделать в запускаемом снипете, но мой плюс ловите в любом случае +

Answer (score 0):

Только если тип данных, передаваемых в функцию, - ссылочный.

```js
function myFunc(params)
{
    params.data++;
}

let dataHolder = { data: 10 };

myFunc(dataHolder);

console.log(dataHolder); // 11
```

Тогда Вы можете внутри функции изменять свойства параметра, и эти изменения будут видны снаружи.

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему костылём:

передаю в качестве параметра функцию

```
function MyFunc(params)
{
    params.my_data(params.my_data() + 1);
}

let data = 10;

myFunc({
    my_data: function(value){
        if (value != undefined)
            data = value;
        return data;
    },
});

console.log(data); // 11
```

Работает, но выглядит коряво очень :(

Answer (score 0):

По ссылке в JavaScript передаются только массивы, объекты и функции. Все остальное копируется.

Объект:

```js
function foo(input) {
    input.a = 2;
    console.log(input);
    console.log(data); // оригинальный объект тоже изменился
}

let data = {a: 1};
foo(data);
```

Массив:

```js
function foo(input) {
        input[0] = 100;
        console.log(input);
        console.log(data); // оригинальный массив тоже изменился
}

let data = [1, 2, 3];
foo(data);
```

Функция: аналогично объекту.

Answer (score 0):

В js (почти) нет связи с переменной по ссылке. И уж точно нет её передачи по ссылке. Соответственно, сделать желаемое разумными способами невозможно.

Как вариант, можно

- вместо переменной использовать поле объекта
- возвращать из функции нечто, что будет обрабатываться вызывающей стороной
- передавать коллбэк вместо переменной