# Оптимизировать код для функции с таймером

Tags: javascript, функции, оптимизация, таймер

Помогите оптимизировать мою функцию для таймера.

```
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10)
});

function startTimer() {
    
    // milliseconds

    milliseconds++;
    millisecondsElement.textContent = addZero(milliseconds);

    if (milliseconds > 99) {
        milliseconds = 0;
        millisecondsElement.textContent = addZero(milliseconds);
        seconds++;
        secondsElement.textContent = addZero(seconds);
    }

    // Seconds

    secondsElement.textContent = addZero(seconds);

    if (seconds > 59) {
        seconds = 0;
        secondsElement.textContent = addZero(seconds);
        minutes++;
        minutesElement.textContent = addZero(minutes);
    }

    // Minutes
    
    minutesElement.textContent = addZero(minutes);

    if (minutes > 59) {
        minutes = 0;
        minutesElement.textContent = addZero(minutes);
        hours++;
        hoursElement.textContent = addZero(hours);
    }

    // Hours 

    if(hours > 24) {
        clearTimer()
    }
}
```

У меня в трёх условиях почти одинаковый код.
Хотелось бы заменить его на функцию, которая принимала бы 4 параметра.

```
function updateClock(currentValue, currentElement, nextValue, nextElement) {
    currentValue = 0;
    currentElement.textContent = addZero(currentValue);
    nextValue++;
    nextElement.textContent = addZero(nextValue);
}
```

Но при вызове такой функции внутри условия, ничего не получается.

Comment: Изменение currentValue внутри функции ни как не влияет на переданный ей параметр (например minutes). то же самое касается и nextValue. либо продолжайте менять их в вызывающей функции, либо поместите все эти переменный в какой то объект и передавайте в функцию сам объект и имена изменяемых в нем полей

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804918/javascript-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: А можно использовать объект типа: `const time = {ms: 0, s: 0, h: 0}` вместо трёх перменных?